# DATOS FUNCIONALES

Tags: datatables, rstudio, dataset

¿Como puedo volver una base de datos corriente a datos funcionales en Rstudio?

La base de datos que tengo esta expresada en 5 momentos de tiempo como lo muestro a continuación:

Id   |  X1_t  | X1_t-1  | X1_t-2 |  X1_t-3 |  X1_t-4  |  X1_t-5

Notese que es la misma variable en 5 momentos de tiempo, quiero crear una función para que en vez de tener 5 campos pueda tener una función demoninada f(X1)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿a partir de 5 valores quieres llegar a obtener una función? Gran parte del corpus de la estadística se dedica justamente a lograr esto con una innumerable cantidad de métodos. Agrega más información, ejemplo de datos, tipo de relación entre las variables, lineal / polinomial / logística,  grados de libertad, etc.